# Jquery selector using the value of data attribute

Tags: jquery

How can one selects an element based on value on its data attribute???
example

```
<button data-present = "one">Present data</button>
```

am trying `$(selector:data('something') == something)`
but it fails

Answer (score 3):

Use [attribute equals](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector

```
$('button[data-present=one]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```js
if($('button').attr('data-present') == 'one'){
 console.log(true);
} else{
 console.log(false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-present = "one">Present data</button>
```